# 360 Panorama image not working in some devices

Tags: android, google-vr, 360-panorama, google-vr-sdk

I am using [this library](https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-android-sdk) to load 360 panorama image,

Its working fine in some devices like google pixel 2 and Nexus 5X but in some devices its not working, How can I make it work on all devices?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Please, give more explain like log crash, code, etc

Comment: @Benjamin its not crashing but it looks like static image, there is no movement in image when  tilt  device.